# forcing mpdf to write all html content to a single long page?

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

i want to write all my html content(a table and some header content) on a single long page.i know that the page size could be specified using mpdf format configuration variable like so:

```
$mpdf=new Mpdf('format' => [$width,$height]);
```

however it seems that `format` expects both width and height values. does mpdf support a way to only specify  page width and the height value will be calculated based on content height?

Comment: Unless you set up the page-size, I'm not so sure if you can set the height dynamically. You can  try to avoid page break using  `page-break-inside: avoid`.

Comment: @NcXNaV page-break-inside: avoid shrinks the content to fit in the page, i need the reverse: i want the page to be shrinked to fit the content.